# Generating dynamic and custom Mac application build(dmg) from the server

Tags: php, ios, iphone, macos

I have a requirement to develop a Mac OSX application. Dmg file creation should be done dynamically. Each user should be delivered with a unique build/bundle that differs in some means, say a difference in algorithm.

1. Is it possible to do a dynamic automated bundle/dmg creation?
2. if it is possible, then which hosting server we should use? Is  it Mac server or any other alternative available ?

My ultimate aim is to create unique Build(dmg) for each user which must be downloaded from the server. How much feasible it is?

Please help.